# ¿Por qué "caramba" indica sorpresa?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología

Con frecuencia usamos "caramba" para indicar sorpresa:

> ¡Caramba! El Barça ha metido cinco goles

Buscando en el DRAE veo distintas acepciones para la palabra:

> **[caramba](http://dle.rae.es/?w=caramba&o=h)<sup>1</sup>**
>
> 1. interj. eufem. U. para expresar extrañeza o enfado.
>
> **caramba<sup>2</sup>**
>
> Por alus. a la Caramba, sobrenombre de María Antonia Fernández,
>   tonadillera española del siglo XVIII.
>
> 1. f. Moña que llevaban las mujeres sobre la cofia, a fines del siglo XVIII.
>
> **caramba<sup>3</sup>**
>
> Quizá de carángano, infl. por caramba1.
>
> 1. f. Hond. quijongo.

Sin embargo, ninguna encaja exactamente con esa sorpresa. Asumiendo que esa significación se da -al menos en España-, ¿con qué acepción y/o con qué origen podríamos asociarlo?

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta que *sorpresa* es sinónimo de *extrañeza*, como puedes ver aquí: http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/sorpresa

Comment: No pienso que en el caso de "caramba" sea un eufemismo - pero es una palabra que puede ser usada para denotar sorpresa y a la vez enojo/enfado. Por ejemplo, _Caramba, hemos ganado el partido!_
o _Caramba, que mal se porta este chico_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es un eufemismo por `carajo`. Extrañamente, el Etymonline tiene una entrada para esta palabra: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=caramba.

Comment: ¡Caramba! No sabía esto. ¿Puedes dar alguna referencia sobre el hecho de que es eufemismo? Parece ser además que la palabra ha cruzado la barrera del idioma y hasta se usa en inglés, sí : )

Comment: @fedorqui  la misma definición del DRAE que citás marca la palabra como "interjección eufemística" :).

Comment: Es cierto que es un eufemismo por carajo. Si bien en el DRAE, la palabra caramba tiene ya una definición, aquí en el primer significado dice claramente "(Eufem. por carajo)." http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=caramba. Agunas veces el DRAE te lleva a la versión precedente o la nueva versión de la 23.ª edición

Answer (score 2):

Probablemente provenga de la canción **un señorito muy petimetre**:

```
Un señorito muy petimetre
Se entró en mi casa cierta mañana
Y así me dijo al primer envite:
“Oiga usted: ¿quiere ser mi pareja?”
Yo le respondí con mi sonete,
Con ni canto, ni baile y soflama:
¡Que chusco es usted, señorito!
Usted quiere… ¡Caramba! ¡Caramba!
¡Que si quieres, quieres, ea!
Vaya, vaya, vaya!
Me volvió a decir muy tierno y fino:
María Antonia, no seas tirana
Mira niña, que te amo y te adoro,
Y tendrás las pesetas a manta.
Yo, le respondí con mi sonete,
Con mi canto, mi baile y soflama:
¡Que porfiado es usted, señorito!
Usted quiere…¡Caramba! ¡Caramba!
```

---

El diccionario te da la pista **María Antonia Fernández**.

*Fuente:* [*María Antonia Vallejo Fernández Wikipedia*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mar%C3%ADa_Antonia_Vallejo)