# ¿Por qué la RAE no usó los signos de apertura de exclamación en su diccionario hasta 1884, si mucho antes ya eran obligatorios?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación, rae, dle

En [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/137/12637) sobre el origen de los símbolos '¿' y '¡' se explica que ambos fueron introducidos en 1754, en la segunda edición de la *Ortografía de la real academia*, aunque su uso por entonces era solo aconsejado. Sí que se hicieron obligatorios en la edición de 1815, como se apunta en [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10329/12637) a [otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10328/12637). Sin embargo, veo la siguiente definición en el diccionario de la RAE de 1822:

[image: Caramba1]

Nótese que la definición carece de dicho signo de apertura. Esta definición se mantiene en 1869:

[image: Caramba2]

Para pasar (por fin) a tener dicho símbolo en la versión de 1884:

[image: Caramba3]

Es de suponer que la RAE debería dar ejemplo con las normas que ella misma promulga. Por tanto, ¿por qué la RAE no usó los signos de apertura de exclamación en su diccionario hasta 1884, más de un siglo después de introducir dicho signo en la ortografía (y más de medio siglo después de que se declararan obligatorios)? ¿Fue porque en la imprenta no disponían de ese símbolo? ¿Hubo algún periodo después de 1815 en el que los símbolos se dejaran de usar para luego volver a ser usados?

Comment: Por alusiones: [¿Por qué “caramba” indica sorpresa?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15062/12637)

Comment: Originalmente las invertidas eran facultativas cuando al principio se las introdujo en la Ortografía. Luego llegaron a ser obligatorias (no recuerdo en qué ediciones precisamente, pero lo recuerdo de la pregunta sobre las ortografías). Obviamente en el período intermedio, serían más comunes las de interrogación, porque puede surgir más confusión entre declarativa e interrogativa que entre declarativa y exclamativa.

Comment: @guifa veo en [tu espectacular respuesta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10329/12637) que en la edición de 1815 de la ortografía "inverted question and exclamation marks now standard". ¿Te refieres con esto a que ahí fue cuando se hicieron obligatorios los signos? Si es así, la pregunta sigue igual: ¿por qué la propia RAE no puso en práctica su uso en el diccionario hasta 1884?

Comment: @guifa actualizada la pregunta con la información aportada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que la afirmación de guifa en [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10329/12637) a la pregunta sobre [la evolución de la ortografía](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10328/12637) no fue del todo precisa. Ojeando el texto de la octava edición de la ortografía de 1815, leo lo siguiente (negritas mías):

> Por lo cual considerando la Academia que desde el principio de la proposición interrogatoria empieza esta mudanza [de entonación], creyó que no era bastante indicar la interrogación al fin, sino que convenía indicarla ya desde el principio: y **para esto propuso, que pues al fin se acostumbraba poner el signo en esta forma (?), al principio se pusiese el mismo, pero inverso de este modo (¿)** [...]. Desde luego adoptó el público este oportuno pensamiento, aunque en la práctica **se ha introducido algún abuso; pues la Academia lo propuso solamente para los períodos largos, en los cuales es necesario; pero ya se pone en preguntas de una o dos palabras en que no se necesita**.

Dice exactamente lo mismo para el caso de los signos de exclamación. Es decir, que en aquella edición de 1815 lo que se hacía era recalcar que el uso que se le había propuesto a los signos (¿) y (¡) en 1754 era el correcto, y que la gente estaba abusando de los signos poniéndolos en oraciones muy cortas cuando no era necesario.

Es por ese motivo que la RAE insistió en su forma de poner los signos (¿) y (¡) hasta 1869. En este año, la definición de "interrogación" en el DLE era la siguiente:

> Nota ó señal de que se usa en la escritura cuando se pregunta, y se usa así (?).

Por eso las definiciones de palabras como *¡Caramba!* solo llevaban el signo de cierre: simplemente estaban siguiendo sus propias normas, al considerar que en una oración de una sola palabra no se debía poner el signo de inicio de exclamación. En la siguiente edición, la de 1884, la misma definición dice así:

> Signo ortográfico (¿?) que se pone al principio y fin de palabra ó cláusula en que se hace pregunta.

Se ve que por fin la RAE decidió en aquella edición seguir una convención más sencilla, decidiendo que era más fácil poner siempre los signos (¿) y (¡) más que dejar que cada uno decida subjetivamente cuándo una oración es lo suficientemente corta como para omitirlo o no.